# Webpack output chunk as commonjs2 library

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to make some React Isomorphic/Universal magic and I needed to be able to `require` in Node an exported chunk.

I'd like to do something like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: [
      './src/index',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'chunk-[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  ...
};
```

**index.jsx**

```
require.ensure(['./reducers', './routes'], (require) => {
  const rootReducer = require('./reducers');
  const routes = require('./routes');
  /* Store/routes/configuration stuff */
  ReactDOM.render(/* components */);
}, 'core');
```

So this would output two files:

- `index.js`: Loaded by the browser
- `chunk-core.js`: *required* by index AND Node server

If I set the output as a library with type `commonjs2` it works on Node, but does not generate my browser bundle, so I'd have to run 2 webpack configs simultaneously: one for the browser bundle and another for the server library.

I'd like to know if any of these are possible:

- output a chunk as commonjs2 library
- output a chunk with a different target as the main output
- import a standard webpack chunk in Node

Comment: These are possible